# Access VBA add a calculated field

Tags: vba, ms-access, macros

I currently have a Macro in Access that will pull in specific CSV files. I am looking to attach VBA code to this macro to also generate a calculated field at the end.

I am able to add the calculated field manually with the expression:

```
IIf([Weight] <= 5, 1, IIf([Weight] <= 10, 2, IIf([Weight] <= 20, 3, IIf([Weight] <= 30, 4, IIf([Weight] <= 50, 5, 6)))))
```

Is there a way to add this calculated field automatically when the macro is run, or via a second macro?

This Access database is just being used to connect to Excel and generate PivotTables from the data. I can create the calculated fields within Excel, but cannot use calculated fields as rows in Pivottables.

Answer (score 1):

You could add this field to a Query then base your Pivots on the Query.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've set up a query with the added field, but when I try to use the query as the data for a PivotTable I get the error: "Data could not be retrieved from the database. Check the database server or contact your database administrator. Make sure the external database is available, and then try the operation again." I am still able to use the table from the database for the PivotTable, so there is no problem connecting to the database.

Comment: @AdamSmith does the query run ok if not used as a pivot? Check for errors in the calculated Field